# Click hyperlink, open in Chrome, copy contents from another cell on-click

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-chrome, macros

I'm trying to:

1. When I click a hyperlink in Column A
2. Have text content in Column B copied to windows clipboard
3. Hyperlinks in Column A open in new Chrome tab

Column A & B will have thousands of rows, each unique to each other (B1 text must be copied to clipboard when A1 link clicked).

Example:
A1: http://thisisawebsitewithinput.com
B2: the_text_string_I_need_copied

This is as far as I've gotten with a macro:

Sub OpenInBrowser()
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=ActiveCell.Text
End Sub

Comment: Open in chrome you only need to set chrome as default browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = [a1].Address Then Cells(1, 2).Copy
End Sub
```

Comment: This is working for cell A1, but going down the line it doesn't seem to copy the next row. Any way to have the clipboard reflect new corresponding rows? Thank you.

http://cnn.com         text1
http://bing.com text2
http://google.com text3